# Dangerous Permissions is auto granted at app install in new project [React Native - Android]

Tags: android, react-native, runtime-permissions

I have installed awesome project from react native cli and run it in android build.
It works fine.

When I added, below dangerous permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in my android manifest.xml and run the project it is auto granted on app install.

I check app info and it is granted by default.

Note:

- Min Version : 23
- Target and Compile Version : 29
- React Native Version: 0.64.0

So when I check permission programmatically it is always granted. It should not.

Comment: You resolve that?

Comment: this thread helped me -- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31278

Answer (score 0):

from RN website :
(https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)

```
const requestPermissions = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: "your title",
        message:
          "your message",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("GPS permission ok");
    } else {
      console.log("GPS permission not ok");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: It is for asking permission from the user. But in my case, I am just declaring permissions in manifest and it is granted. Dangerous permissions.